# Exit button is not working not working properly

Tags: java, javafx

I got the computing part of the program done, but I can't figure out how to get the clear button I made to clear the fields and the exit button to close the program.

I have tried different things for both, but I haven't been able to get them to work.

I was able to replicate the code to compute for both of the other buttons, just not get them to work as intended.

```
public class JavaFXPaycheckJava extends Application {
// define the constants
    public static final double OVERTIME_RATE = 1.5;   // time and a half
    public static final double TAX_RATE = 0.17;       // 0.17 is 17%

    // list of controls on the scene
    private static Label lblTitle;
    private static Label lblHours;
    private static Label lblPayRate;
    private static Button btnCompute;
    private static TextField txtHours;
    private static TextField txtPayRate;
    private static TextArea txtPaycheck; 
    private static Button btnClear;
    private static Button btnExit;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        createControls (root);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 320);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX Paycheck Project");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


     // process the Compute button click event

    private static void btnComputeClick() {
        double hours;
        double payRate;
        double regHours, overtimeHours;
        double regPay, overtimePay;
        double grossPay, taxes, netPay;

        // input the hours and payRate from the TextFields
        try {
            hours = Double.valueOf(txtHours.getText());
            payRate = Double.valueOf(txtPayRate.getText());
            if (hours < 0 || payRate < 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Inputs must be positive");
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            txtPaycheck.setText("Values for hours and pay rate must be numeric"); 
            return; // no more processing
        }  
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            txtPaycheck.setText(e.getMessage()); 
            return; // no more processing
        }

        // compute the regHours and overtimeHours
        if (hours <= 40) {              // Less or = to 40 hours, then
            regHours = hours;           //   all hours are regular
            overtimeHours = 0.0;        //   with no overtime
        }
        else {                          // Over 40 hours, then
            regHours = 40.0;            //    first 40 at regular pay
            overtimeHours = hours-40.0; //    anything over 40
        }

        // compute the paycheck
        regPay = regHours * payRate;
        overtimePay = overtimeHours * payRate * OVERTIME_RATE;
        grossPay = regPay + overtimePay;
        taxes = grossPay * TAX_RATE;
        netPay = grossPay - taxes;

        // display the paycheck, formatted with 2 digits past the decimal
        txtPaycheck.setText( 
                String.format("Your gross pay is $%.2f\n", grossPay) +
                String.format("Your taxes are    $%.2f\n", taxes) +
                String.format("Your net pay is   $%.2f", netPay) );

    } // end of btnCompute_Click
    private static void btnClearClick(){





    }// end of ClearClick
    private static void btnExitClick(){


    }//end of ExitClick

    private static void createControls(Pane root) {
        Font font24B = Font.font("Ariel", FontWeight.BOLD, 24); // title
        Font font18  = Font.font("Ariel", FontWeight.NORMAL, 18); // 

        lblTitle = new Label("Paycheck Calculator");
            lblTitle.setFont(font24B);          // large-bold font
            lblTitle.setLayoutX(12);
            lblTitle.setLayoutY(4);
            root.getChildren().add(lblTitle);

        lblHours = new Label("Hours");
            lblHours.setFont(font18);           // normal font, size=18
            lblHours.setLayoutX(24);
            lblHours.setLayoutY(57);
            root.getChildren().add(lblHours);

        txtHours = new TextField();
            txtHours.setFont(font18);
            txtHours.setLayoutX(123);
            txtHours.setLayoutY(57);
            txtHours.setMaxSize(119,30);        
            txtHours.setMinSize(119,30);
            root.getChildren().add(txtHours);

        lblPayRate = new Label("Pay Rate");
            lblPayRate.setFont(font18);
            lblPayRate.setLayoutX(24);
            lblPayRate.setLayoutY(101);
            root.getChildren().add(lblPayRate);

        txtPayRate = new TextField();
            txtPayRate.setFont(font18);
            txtPayRate.setLayoutX(123);
            txtPayRate.setLayoutY(95);
            txtPayRate.setMaxSize(119,30);
            txtPayRate.setMinSize(119,30);
            root.getChildren().add(txtPayRate);

        btnCompute = new Button("Compute");
            btnCompute.setFont(font18);
            btnCompute.setLayoutX(40);
            btnCompute.setLayoutY(148);
            btnCompute.setMaxSize(110,40);      
            btnCompute.setMinSize(110,40);
            btnCompute.setOnAction( e -> btnComputeClick() );
            btnCompute.setOnKeyPressed (e -> btnComputeClick() );
            root.getChildren().add(btnCompute);

        btnClear = new Button("Clear");
            btnClear.setFont(font18);
            btnClear.setLayoutX(180);
            btnClear.setLayoutY(148);
            btnClear.setMaxSize(110,40);     
            btnClear.setMinSize(110,40);
            btnClear.setOnAction( e -> btnClearClick() );
            btnClear.setOnKeyPressed (e -> btnClearClick() );
            root.getChildren().add(btnClear);

        btnExit = new Button("Exit");
            btnExit.setFont(font18);
            btnExit.setLayoutX(320);
            btnExit.setLayoutY(148);
            btnExit.setMaxSize(110,40);      
            btnExit.setMinSize(110,40);
            btnExit.setOnAction( e -> btnExitClick() );
            btnExit.setOnKeyPressed (e -> btnExitClick() );
            root.getChildren().add(btnExit);    

        txtPaycheck = new TextArea();          // TextArea to display the paycheck
            txtPaycheck.setFont(font18);
            txtPaycheck.setLayoutX(40);
            txtPaycheck.setLayoutY(205);
            txtPaycheck.setMinSize(400,100);
            txtPaycheck.setMaxSize(400,100);
            txtPaycheck.setEditable(false); // don't let user change paycheck
            enter code hereroot.getChildren().add(txtPaycheck);       
    } // end of createControls()

} // end of class JavaFXPaycheck
```

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: why all the static declarations? Hint: there's rarely a reason, so remove all except the constant declarations and the main

Answer (score 0):

`btnExitClick()` method does nothing. Change it to:

```
 private static void btnExitClick(){
    Platform.exit();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Clearing**. You need action on your button

```
btnClear.setOnAction(e->{
lblTitle.setText("");
lblHours.setText("");
...
});
```

**Closing**

```
btnExit.setOnAction(e->{
stage.close();
});
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error for the stage close.  Saying cant find variable stage

Comment: `btnExit` has this `btnExit.setOnKeyPressed (e -> btnExitClick() );`

Comment: I know I changed it to stage.close, but it still gives me the error that it can't find the variable stage for that